# Why does Facebook's Infer tool warn about a resource leak in this code?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, resource-leak

When run on the following code, Facebook's Infer tool gives the following output:

```
Analysis finished in 397mss

Found 1 issue

test.c:18: error: RESOURCE_LEAK
  resource of type `_IO_FILE` acquired by call to `fopen()` at line 13, column 13 is not released after line 18, column 2.
  16.           return 1;
  17.       }
  18. >     fp = check_file_size_and_reopen(fp);
  19.   
  20.       fclose(fp);


Summary of the reports

  RESOURCE_LEAK: 1
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define FILE_MAX_SIZE   256000
#define FILE_NAME       "dump.log"
#define LAST_FILE_NAME  "dump.log2"

FILE* check_file_size_and_reopen(FILE* fp);

int main(void) {

    FILE *fp = fopen(FILE_NAME, "a+");

    if (!fp) {
        return 1;
    }
    fp = check_file_size_and_reopen(fp);

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}

FILE* check_file_size_and_reopen(FILE* fp) {
    struct stat info;

    fstat(fileno(fp), &info);

    if (info.st_size > FILE_MAX_SIZE) {
        fclose(fp);
        rename(FILE_NAME, LAST_FILE_NAME);
        fp = fopen(FILE_NAME,"a+");
    }

    return fp;  
}
```

It gives the same warning if the file pointer is passed in as a `FILE** fp` and modified, but not if the call to `check_file_size_and_reopen()` is replaced with identical code inline.

Is this because Infer can't be sure that `fp` hasn't been modified before the call to `fclose()` when passed to another function, or is there actually a potential resource leak here?

UPDATE

Interestingly, it seems to be the call to `fstat()` that is upsetting infer. The following has no warnings:

```
FILE* check_file_size_and_reopen(FILE* fp) {
    struct stat info;
    int fd = fileno(fp);
    (void)fd;

    info.st_size = 0;

    if (info.st_size <= FILE_MAX_SIZE) {
        return fp;  
    }

    fclose(fp);
    rename(FILE_NAME, LAST_FILE_NAME);

    return fopen(FILE_NAME,"a+");
}
```

However, this has the same warning as before:

```
FILE* check_file_size_and_reopen(FILE* fp) {
    struct stat info;
    int fd = fileno(fp);

    fstat(fd, &info);

    if (info.st_size <= FILE_MAX_SIZE) {
        return fp;  
    }

    fclose(fp);
    rename(FILE_NAME, LAST_FILE_NAME);

    return fopen(FILE_NAME,"a+");
}
```

Comment: looks like false positive to me

Comment: The actual error is not a resource leak but the opposite, passing an invalid pointer to `fclose` if the second `fopen` fails.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible it's getting angry about re-assigning `fp`, so you could just side-step that:

```c
FILE* check_file_size_and_reopen(FILE* fp) {
    struct stat info;

    fstat(fileno(fp), &info);

    if (info.st_size <= FILE_MAX_SIZE) {
      return fp;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    rename(FILE_NAME, LAST_FILE_NAME);
    return fopen(FILE_NAME,"a+");
}
```

Comment: This did not change infer's output. It seems to be the call to ```fstat()``` that it doesn't like

Comment: Is it under the impression that `fileno()` consumes the handle?

Comment: It gives no warnings if I keep the call to ```fileno()``` but omit ```fstat()```

Comment: Replace with a call to `stat(FILE_NAME, &info)`?

Comment: The warning persists, even if the call is something like ```stat("~/.ackrc", &info)``` or some other completely unrelated file